# Json Deserialization Exception while working with RiotAPI Via Winforms

Tags: c#, json, api, winforms

trying to deserialize some data from Riot API however I am getting exception errors. These are hitting at the line List Summoners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List>((json)); of my RiotAPIForm.Cs.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace RiotAPI_ESavage
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/Vine?api_key=KEYHERE");
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SummonerV4>>((string)apiResponse);
        //MessageBox.Show(json); FOR TESTING 
    }

    public object apiResponse { get; private set; }

    private void GetAPIData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   //Move load into into click to give windowed response. 
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/Vine?api_key=KEYHERE");
        List<SummonerV4> Summoners = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SummonerV4>>((json));
        //var riotApi = RiotApi.NewInstance("RGAPI-b3258901-3962-4724-936d-e9b1878043dd");
        //var Summoner = riotApi.SummonerV4.GetBySummonerName(Region.NA, textBox1);
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = Summoners;



    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}
`
This is the SummonerV4.CS I'm refering to.

```
    public class SummonerV4
```

{

```
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string AccountID { get; set; }
    public string PuuID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }    
    public long RevisionDate { get; set; }
    public long SummerLevel { get; set; }


}
```

I'm basically trying to input a username and then output the RiotAPI info into a winforms project.
I'm very new at programming so I do appreciate the patience.

Comment: _I am getting exception errors_.. can you provide details, and ideally sample Json?

Comment: Also, you've left your actual API key in the question! If you can't just change it, I suggest you edit the question to remove it and ask a moderator to remove it from the question history. (Json deserializing is case-sensitive on property names, by the way)

Comment: The type of material I want to output into the data field would be the following 

{
    "id": "ffVbrew02I7mPrqaSd9wsLG5Yk1ZcaNoXU6dpuqLUC1-0s0",
    "accountId": "OlnQsTk7UBWNVIclNES3xuazoF4m2XL-ab5f1umAHdActQ",
    "puuid": "3SpqlqZL0JDtsCCPwJrlQO-G5SjbNzoyFGToN3EbpGreFSENaeu8zYWjTVSAu1RqdowW-nMTZheBOg",
    "name": "PKultra",
    "profileIconId": 4479,
    "revisionDate": 1580760850000,
    "summonerLevel": 106
}

Refer to https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#summoner-v4/GET_getBySummonerName

Comment: I would expect deserialiiztion to not return values as your class properties don't match the Json properties (including case!) - `SummerLevel`instead of `summonerLevel`, `ProfileIconId` instead of `profileIconId` - but without you telling us what exceptions you get, it's hard to know what the problem might be.

Comment: Also, the Json you've provided is a single object - as the docs you've linked to say - but you're trying to deserialize it into a List, which I suspect might be the problem here.

Comment: How would I reformat it so it is not a list? I apologize I'm pretty lost.

Comment: `var summoner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerV4>(apiResponse);` but you'll need to either change your class properties to match the Json names, or use the `JsonProperty` attribute to alias them, so for example on `ProfileIconId` you'd add the attribute as `JsonProperty["profileIconId"]`

Comment: See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm for examples

Comment: I got the names in SummonerV4.cs to match what the Json would look like coming from the API however am still getting an unhandled exception: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SummonerV4]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."

Comment: This is coming from Private void GetAPIData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   method

Comment: Like I said above **the API call returns a single object**. You can’t create a list from that.